# How to calculate numbers from loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm new in python and i'm trying to calculate numbers from loop. Let this question make easy for you to understand.

I've this program in python:

```
print("Please enter your case:")

myCase = input("\nEnter: ")

for numCase in range(0, int(myCase)):
    print("\nPlease enter your number: ")
    myNum = input("\nEnter: ")

    for i in myNum:
        divideNum = int(myNum) % int(i)
        print(divideNum)
```

Now After running this program, it gives the following output:

```
    Please enter your case:

    Enter: 2

    Please enter your number: 

    Enter: 456856
    0
    1
    4
    0
    1
    4

    Please enter your number: 

    Enter: 12
    0
    0

    //You could see here, these are the result of the remainder.
```

***QUESTION***

I want to calculate that zero occurs `two` times at case 1 and case 2. You can see that into my program i'm calculating `Remainder` at given inputs.

Here is another example to understand!

Suppose, I give input:

```
Enter: 25621
1
1
1
1
0
```

Now, Here i want to calculate that zero occurs at `one time`. So, how to achieve that process in python?

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of zeros in the calculated values you have many option.

Here are two:

Use variable to store the count:

```
zeros_count = 0
for i in myNum:
    divideNum = int(myNum) % int(i)
    print(divideNum)
    if divideNum == 0:
        # value is 0, add 1 to the count
        zeros_count = zeros_count + 1
print("number of zeros: %d" % zeros_count)
```

Or create a list of zeros from the values using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and then use the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function, which embeds the loop in the list construction:

```
zeros_count = len([i for i in myNum if i == '0'])
print("number of zeros: %d" % zeros_count)
```

Comment: If you take a closer look, he is not converting the input to an int, so it is actually a string (which is an iterable), and he is converting inside the loop context only.